# NSInvalidArgumentException when setting nil UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using the `UserDefaults` to store a values into the preferences.

I have a template class and a method to get the value ( needed to be overridden )

```
func getValue(_ value: T?) -> Any?
{
    return value
}
```

When i'am calling:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(getValue(value), forKey: "pref_key")
```

where `value` can be `nil`,
i get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
>   list object null for key pref_key'

Wasn't it supposed to remove the key if the value is nil?

Comment: Are you return `nil` or `NSNull` from your `getValue` method?

Comment: nil, but some values may be NSNull, wasn't it supposed to support both?

Comment: No, you can't store `NSNull` in UserDefaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is an attempt to store a value of `NSNull` in `UserDefaults`. This isn't supported. `nil` is fine, it simply removes any existing value. But `NSNull` is not the same thing as `nil`.

You need to deal with this. Here's one solution:

```
var val = getValue(value)
if val is NSNull {
    val = nil
}
UserDefaults.standard.set(val, forKey: "pref_key")
```

Comment: It's working if I set it directly, but not throw the method. I also printed it and is nil, I think it's a language limitation, maybe Any is changing it in some way

Comment: I am testing "if" value == nil or is NSNull, but "if" fails no both cases, and if i print it, the output is nil. I can't understand the behaviour

Comment: I found that value is wrapped into String?? and even if is nil will fail the if condition. Any idea?